# Get activity over time for a specific question

Tags: feature-request, api, site-analytics, data-dump

Is there already any way to find out when page views & question votes have occurred over time for a specific question?  Clearly this info is publicly available for comments & answers, but what about the metrics that just get summed up like views and votes?  I'm not looking for identities, just trends over time.  Is this available in the raw data dump?  Or maybe through google site analytics with 25k reputation?

My motivation is that I'm digging up an old question that has had a lot of total activity, and I'm trying to figure out if the question refers to a transient issue that resolved itself, or if it's something people are still worried about (~= searching for and voting on).

(Tagging as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) under the assumption this isn't currently possible.)

Comment: Try /posts/<questionid>/timeline  Not very granular, but it's aggregated by day, I believe.

Comment: The votes table in SEDE has accept/up/down and posthistory has all other events for a post

Comment: Is this helpful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372772/578411

Answer (score 1):

This is already possible (and easy) with existing tools like `/posts/<questionid>/timeline`.  Thanks y'all!